# adding graphics to if and else statements in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting an error message when trying to display a 'third' graphic on the app. I went around and changed curly brackets but still can't make it work. Could someone point out what am I missing?
With the help of @stefan here: [Select current plot and download to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774692/select-current-plot-and-download-to-file/72775562#72775562)
works like a charm with two graphics but having trouble adding more graphics to it.
Here is what I got:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define input choices
type <- c("first", "second","third")
# Data for lambda
table <- structure(list(year = 1991:2010, lambda = c(
  0.68854, 0.75545,
  1.63359, 1.22282, 1.70744, 1.09692, 0.51159, 1.3904, 1.09132,
  0.59846, 0.43055, 0.80135, 0.69027, 0.65646, 0.95485, 1.04818,
  0.67859, 1.00461, 1.16665, 1.28203
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    h3(""),
    
    # Dropdown to select the desired kind of graphic
    selectInput(
      inputId = "graphtype",
      label = "Graphic",
      choices = type,
      selected = "first"
    ),
    checkboxInput("Fixed", "Fixed Y axes", FALSE),
    downloadButton("downloadPlot", "Download Plot"),
    radioButtons(inputId = "type", label = "Select the file type", choices = list("png", "pdf"))
  ),
  # Graphic Area mainPanel. Graphic on top and table right below it
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
)

######################
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  # Plot data
  create_plot <- reactive({
    xlabels <- 1991:2011
    if (input$graphtype == "first") {
      ggplot(table, aes(year, lambda)) +
        geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "blue") +
        geom_point(colour = "orange", size = 4) +
        scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
        labs(x = "", y = "test", title = paste0("Population growth rate of Fish "))
    } #else{
        else if (input$graphtype == "second") {
        ggplot(table, aes(year, lambda)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "red") +
          geom_point(colour = "green", size = 4) +
          scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
          labs(x = "", y = "fish test", title = paste0("Population growth"))
      } else {
        ggplot(table, aes(year, lambda)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "yellow") +
          geom_point(colour = "green", size = 4) +
          scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
          labs(x = "", y = "fish test", title = paste0("Population growth"))
      }
      else if (input$graphtype == "third"){
        ggplot(table, aes(year, lambda)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "goldenrod") +
          geom_point(colour = "green", size = 4) +
          scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
          labs(x = "", y = "fish test", title = paste0("Population growth"))
      } else {
        ggplot(table, aes(year, lambda)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "brown") +
          geom_point(colour = "green", size = 4) +
          scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
          labs(x = "", y = "fish test", title = paste0("Population growth")) 
      }
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    create_plot()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The issue is that you have two `else` branches, i.e. you could have multiple `else if` but only one `else`.

Comment: is supposed to display a 'red' line if the checkboxInput is checked or 'yellow if is not. And the third graphic as well. But oopps I think I forgot to add those conditions.

Comment: Working now after I added the checkbox , thanks again @stefan....